# Best way to create a proxy pool in php using guzzle or curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy, connection-pooling, guzzle

**Question:** What would be the best way to create a proxy pool in php, my initial thoughts are to use CURL or Guzzle.

**Usecase:** I have x amount of proxies which i usually connect to on a rolling basis, im trying to think what the best option is where i can create a pool of all the proxies which are pre-connected and then pass my request to the pool of connected proxies to complete the request. The problem with this approach is each time i drop a connection and connect to the next proxy it adds a short delay and my use case means latency is critical so i am trying to avoid having to disconnect and connect to the next proxy by already having a pool of connected proxies.

**Goal:** To achieve the lowest latency by passing a request to the proxy pool to be completed by one of the already established proxy connections.

Answer (score 0):

> To achieve the lowest latency by passing a request to the proxy pool to be completed by one of the already established proxy connections.

In PHP (using cURL) you cannot control connection pool directly, cURL maintains it inside the lib. But you can specify some options to set its size.

Take a look at [the docs about creating CurlMultiHandler](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-add-custom-curl-options). There are `CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS` and `CURLMOPT_MAX_HOST_CONNECTIONS` options that you are interested in. So if you only do you requests via predefined list of proxy servers, these settings will regulate your connection pool size to your proxies.

Also take a look at [CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and check that you are using HTTP 1.1 (keepalive is not supported in HTTP 1.0)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help, Lets say i have 1,000 proxies.. Would it be possible to open curl connections to each of the proxies and keep the connection open for a long period.. then i can pass my request to the pool of 1000 proxies which would already be connected therefore i should be able to avoid the delay of opening the connection.. making the request then closing the connection before moving onto the next proxy.. instead i would be able to just make the request and then move to the next proxy because the 1,000 are connected and stored in a pool / array... Would this be possible?